CapsLock as input source switch while typing – instant switching?
I'm trying to make CapsLock switch input sources between Eng and Ukr without interrupting my typing. Even after applying 0 caps delay hidutil property --set '{"CapsLockDelayOverride":0}, I don't see much improvement
The problem is while typing quickly in one language, I need to pause, press and release CS, and then continue typing so I’d like CL to instantly switch input sources even if other keys are pressed at the same time
Is there any way to configure CS to change the input source on-the-fly, without needing to pause typing or release other keys first? I’m open to any solutions — scripts, third-party apps (like Keyboard Maestro, KE etc.)

For super fast switching, you could try making a custom layout with Ukelele with English on the caps lock level of the ukr keyboard

Thanks, I've heard of it but never tried. Hope it's not too complicated

Can't make comments, but are you familiar with Hammerspoon? You could make a simple Lua script to achieve what you want.

Interesting, can you tell me more about it?
